# Set valid time interval for login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to allow to login only within concrete time interval.
my spring security config:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="provider1"/>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="provider2"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

please advise proper place for this check.

### P.S.

For example I need to allow log in since 9-00 to 20:00. If user tries to login at 8-39 with valid credentials - he should get auth fail

Comment: Do you use your own implementation of AuthenticationProvider? if so, you can check the time in authenticate() method and through custom exception.

Comment: @Jahangir Alam I use 2 providers. I want to make this check in single place

Comment: User will be validated within authenticate method. I wounder if there is any feature like on before authentication in spring security. If you use multiple providers they will be called sequentially. If the user is validated in one provider the next provider will not be called.